# Paged Category Query with Rows returns always posts even if empty

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a custom query with rows every 3 posts. In a paged category it always returns 12 posts even if the category is empty. Any tips what am I doing wrong?

```
    <?php 
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged'          => $paged
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    $counter = 0;
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
        if ($counter % 3 == 0) :
            echo $counter > 0 ? "<div class='clear'></div></div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
            echo "<div class='row'>";
        endif;
        ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'templates/3columnpost', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php
        $counter++;

    endwhile;
         endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: If the category is empty, what is getting returning? Also, what file is this in e.g. archive.php, category.php etc?

Comment: @FluffyKitten The category page always show 12 last posts even if it's empty. This is in category.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the Wordpress loop by calling `WP_Query`, so it is getting all posts.

There are a number of ways to set the number of posts per page. I suggest you do #1 if possible, but if not then 2 is the next best option.

**1. Set the posts per page in Wordpress Admin**

The default Wordpress Loop shows the number of posts that is set in the `Admin Settings` -> `Reading` page under in "**Blog pages show at most**".  You can change this to 12.

If you use this, you will also need to change your code to remove the WP_Query altogether and use the default loop so it will display just the category posts again, e.g.

```
// Check if there are any posts to display
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    // do whatever you need to do before you start displaying the posts       
    // The Loop:
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

        // display the post here

    endwhile;      
endif;
```

Note that this changes the number of posts for *all* post types

**2. Change the number of posts per page in functions.php**

If you only want to change the number of posts per page for a specific post type, you can do it in your functions.php, e.g.

```
function set_custom_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'movie' ) ) {
        // Display 12 posts for a custom post type called 'movie'
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_custom_posts_per_page', 1 );
```

Ref [Wordpress Codex pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Changing_the_number_of_posts_per_page.2C_by_post_type)

**3. Use WP_Query** - note, this resets the loop

WP_Query resets the loop altogether, so if you *have* to use it, then you will need to pass the category id in the `$args` so that Wordpress returns only posts in that category.

```
// get the category id in the query before we reset it using WP_Query
$categoryid = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'category'       => $categoryid
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged'          => $paged
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :

    // whatever you need to do before you start displaying the posts
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

    // display your posts

    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: thanks! I used 1st option and now it works great. I tried your 3rd option but it returned all last 12 posts. In tag.php I have a similar query calling $tag_slug = $tag->slug; and it works fine, dunno what was happening actually. The thing is that now it works! thanks!